# How to change background and font color of QListView using HTML/CSS in qt5

Tags: html, c++, css, qt5

How can i change the color of QListView

i have my QListView like this

```
view=new QListView(this);
view->setGeometry(180,280,300,20);
```

I want to change background color and font color using HTML/CSS codes

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You should also read the [style sheet documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html).

Comment: I used setStyleSheet ("QListView{background-color: blue;}"); and its works, but is it possible to do using HTML code such as <font color='orange'> or something like that.